# Convert HTML page to an image

Tags: php, html-rendering

I want to change my HTML page as an image. Is there a way in PHP to change or save an HTML page as an image?

Comment: Not without an HTML rendering engine. What you want is to screencap a browser screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy; as NullUserException says in his comment, you would need to render the HTML page on the server-side, which is not something PHP (or any other server-sided language) has built in.

The approach that comes to mind would be to write a program (probably not in PHP, but rather something like C# or C++) that runs on your server, fires up a web browser, and does a series of screen captures (possibly combined with page scrolls). As this is a very nontrivial and bug-prone process, I would suggest looking into third-party components that are capable of doing this.

You would then execute this program from PHP, and when it's done running, display the results from the file it output.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use an external service with an api. This list might be a good start: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2008/07/10/9-ways-to-put-site-screenshots-in-your-web-app/

Thumbalizr seems great, they allso provide a php script so you can cache the images locally: 
http://www.thumbalizr.com/apitools.php

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at browsershots.org - source code is available for it if you want to install it locally. Essentially it uses a browser to take screenshots, and can be controlled via an XML-RPC interface, which you can call from PHP.

As others have said this is not a simple job, and not something you can do directly in PHP, so use an external service.

(I'm not affiliated with browsershots.org in any way)